# If I split one video into 2 in Capcut mobile app is there a way to merge them again?

Tags: video-editor, editing, video-recording

I Googled, watched YouTube tutorials and none have the answer. Please keep in mind that I am asking about the Capcut mobile app and not the Pc version

Comment: What does the user guide for the mobile app say about merging files?